# Angular store date value in localStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Hey I would like to store time of login to the localStorage. I checked similar topics and I think it should work but I have problem with typescript (totally new for me) error : Argument of type 'Date' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

```
function(a){ 
    var date = localStorage.setItem('logTime', new Date),
        date = new Date(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('logTime')));

    if (value < date) { console.log("string") }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

IN this line

```
date = new Date(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('logTime')));
```

You are trying to assign to string variable another type of variable.
You should convert Data type to string type.
Just add `.toString()`

```
date = new Date(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('logTime'))).toString(); // Sun Mar 19 2017 23:00:06 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

But I see in next step you equal values. Better equal time in linux timestamp format. In that case add `.getTime()` for convert time into linux timestamp format, and than add `.toString()` for convert timestamp into string format.

```
date = new Date(parseInt(localStorage.getItem('logTime'))).getTime().toString(); // 1489960817920
```